# Linear Transformation and changing the basis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

$T:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ defined by:

$$ T(x,y) = (x+y,y) $$

Now we pick one vector $u_1 = (2,3)$, then- $$ T(u_1) = (2+3,3) = (5,3)\tag{1} $$

So far so good.

Now lets consider a Basis $B = \{u_1, u_2\}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$. I want to do above calulaction in Basis B and then will convert back to standard basis.
$$[u_1]_B = (1,0)$$
$$T([u_1]_B) = (1+0,0) = (1,0)\tag{2}$$
Here $T([u_1]_B)$ is in Basis $B$, since transformation doesn't change basis and our input $[u_1]_B$ is in Basis B therefore output $T([u_1]_B)$ is also in basis $B$. 
Lets convert output back to standard basis -
$$\big[T([u_1]_B)\big]_B = (1,0)$$
$$T([u_1]_B) = (2,3)\tag{3}$$

Sorry for abuse of notation at eq. $(2)$. In equation $(2)$ LHS is $\big[T([u_1]_B)\big]_B$ .

My questions are-

- Can we pass a vector w.r.t any arbitrary basis $B$ inside transformation definition? $\big($Is it even legal to do something like $(2)$ or we always need to pass a standard basis vector in $T(.)$ $\big)$.
- What does it mean to solve something like equation $(2)$ ?.
- How Can we achieve $ T(u_1)$ given $\big[T([u_1]_B)\big]_B$? (If we change the basis and transform a vector, then how does it relate to transformed vector without changing the basis).

These questions might sound layman but I was not able to figure out answer. Any quick help would also be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You are misunderstanding the concepts. If $x$ is any vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$, and $\beta = \{v_1,v_2\}$ is a basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$, then $x$ can be written uniquely as $x = a_1v_1 + a_2v_2$ for some choice of constants $a_1$ and $a_2$, right? In this case, we define the coordinate vector of $x$ with respect to $\beta$ to be
$$[x]_\beta := \begin{pmatrix} a_1\\a_2 \end{pmatrix}.$$

Also, if $\gamma$ is another basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$, we define the matrix representation of $T$ with respect to $\beta$ and $\gamma$ (in that order!) to be the matrix $[T]_\beta^\gamma$ whose first and second column are $[T(v_1)]_\gamma$ and $[T(v_2)]_\gamma$, respectively.

Now, we have the relationship $[T(x)]_\gamma = [T]_\beta^\gamma [x]_\beta$. For example, let $x = (2,3)$, $\beta = \{(1,1),(1,0)\}$, $\gamma = \{(1,0),(0,1)\}$ and $T$ as defined above. Then, $T(x) = (5,3)$ and it is easy to see that
$$[T(x)]_\gamma = \begin{pmatrix} 5\\3 \end{pmatrix}.$$

On the other hand, since $T(1,1) = (2,1)$ and $T(1,0) = (1,0)$, the matrix of $T$ is given  by
$$[T]_\beta^\gamma = \begin{pmatrix} 2&1\\1&0 \end{pmatrix},$$
and, of course, since $x = 3(1,1) + (-1)(1,0)$,
$$[T]_\beta^\gamma [x]_\beta = \begin{pmatrix} 2&1\\1&0 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 3\\-1 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 5\\3 \end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: Thanks Azifoo. I already know the concept that you have described. My question is bit different. Can we do something like $T([x]_\beta)$ ? and how does it relate to $T(x)$?.

Comment: No, $[x]_\beta$ is a $2 \times 1$ matrix, whereas $x$ is a 2-tuple of real numbers. And, the relation $[T(x)]_\gamma = [T]_\beta^\gamma [x]_\beta$ is all that you need, what's exactly your problem where are you stuck?

Comment: when a transformation definition is given (like in above question) then we always need to pass standard basis vector to that ? Cant we pass coordinates of a vector wrt other basis ?. And when a transformation function definition is given then it is sensitive to basis ?
What I mean is, cant we use same definition for different basis other than standard basis.  Specifically I want to use $T(x,y) = (x+y,y)$ in basis B.

Comment: @user3699192 That’s not the same transformation as the original, though.

Comment: yeah thanks.  Thanks for understanding my question. I request you to kindly tell me in more detail by answering below question-

When we define a transformation function then it is always specific to standard basis.? And given a transformation function $T$, can we have an equivalent function $L$ that does the same job for different basis $B$.  i.e. $T(v) = \big[L([v]_B)\big]_Z$ where $Z$ is standard basis.

Comment: @amd, Azif00,
I still have same doubt. Would request you to kindly help me with same.

Comment: When you’re working with $\mathbb K^n$ for some scalar field $\mathbb K$ and the basis is unspecificed, the standard basis is tacitly assumed. However....

Comment: ... as in many other questions here, it’s important to distinguish between vectors and their coordinates, especially when the vector space itself consists of tuples of scalars. If we denote the standard basis of $\mathbb R^n$ by $\mathcal E$, a vector $v$ and its coordinates $[v]_{\mathcal E}$ are different objects even though they look the same. Fixing a basis of a real vector space $V$ defines an isomorphism between $V$ and $\mathbb R^n$, so in a sense $[v]_\mathcal E$ lives in another copy of $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: With that in mind, asking if the definition of $T$ assumes the standard basis doesn’t really make sense: $\mathbb R^2$ is the set $\{(x,y)\mid x,y\in\mathbb R\}$, i.e., all ordered pairs of real numbers, and $T$ is defined by its action on an arbitrary element of this set. The idea of a basis doesn’t enter into any of that.